# How can retrieve the value of a label in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to change the color of a label if another label says true.

I have tried this:

```
var color = ($(mobilelabel_596).text())
if (color===true) { 
$(element).css({'color':"#900"}); 
}
```

But I keep getting errors that say "User transformation function exception. Reason:  mobilelabel_596 is not defined".

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: is `mobilelabel_5961` a variable in your javascript, or is it the `id` or `class` of the label?  My guess is the latter, so, `$('#mobilelabel_596')` or `$('.mobilelabel_596')`

Answer (score 0):

As tom said your jQuery systex is not clear. Also you are checking string with boolean `color === true` it has to be `color=="true"`

This will help you

```
<label id="someid">true</label>

<div id="div1"> Testing</div>

mobilelabel_596="#someid";
element="#div1";

var color = $(mobilelabel_596).text();

if (color=="true") { 
    $(element).css({'color': "blue"}); 
}
```

[See this code in action (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ncr32981/)